# Compare column 1 of two csv files and find the nearest match with >= && <, then print pairs

Tags: linux

Here are some examples (snippets of large files). The first file example has file1 larger than file2 and some of the time stamps match, while some don't. The desired output will have the headers with them, but if too difficult, then I can put them in later. The second file example has file1 smaller than file2, so I need to attach a file1 row that best matches a file2 row (with >= and < logic). As you can see the time in seconds varies from both files and examples, so some will match exactly while some are close.

I can easily find all exact time matches, but not > and < comparisons.

This code  kind of works, but  leaves out many of the beginning rows. Iv'e
tried rearranging this code to provide the below "Desired" output, but no
success.

```
awk -F, '
BEGIN           {CNT+=2
            }
NR == FNR       {a[NR] = $0
             b[NR] = $1
             next
            }
$1 >= b[CNT]    {CNT++
            }
$1 <  b[CNT]    {print a[CNT-1]
             print $0, RS
            }
' file1 file2
```

File 1:

```
TIMEFORMATTED,G_TP01_OPER_ID,G_TP01_OPER_ID(RAW),G_TP02_PROC_NO,G_TP02_PROC_NO(R    
2016/05/25 16:25:19,0,0,0,NO_DEF,-2147483647
2016/05/25 16:25:20,0,0,0,NO_DEF,-2147483648
2016/05/25 16:25:21,0,0,0,NO_DEF,-2147483649
2016/05/25 16:25:22,0,0,0,NO_DEF,-2147483650
2016/05/25 16:25:23,0,0,0,NO_DEF,-2147483651
2016/05/25 16:25:24,0,0,0,NO_DEF,-2147483652
2016/05/25 16:25:25,0,0,0,NO_DEF,-2147483653
2016/05/25 16:25:26,0,0,0,NO_DEF,-2147483654
2016/05/25 16:25:27,0,0,0,NO_DEF,-2147483655
```

File 2:

```
TIMEFORMATTED,HDR_SYNC,HDR_SEC,HDR_MSEC,G_CCSDS_VERSION,G_CCSDS_VERSION(RAW)
2016/05/25 16:25:22,464374526,1464193527,206,0,0
2016/05/25 16:25:26,464374526,1464193532,206,0,0
2016/05/25 16:25:31,464374526,1464193537,207,0,0
```

Desired Output:

```
TIMEFORMATTED,G_TP01_OPER_ID,G_TP01_OPER_ID(RAW),G_TP02_PROC_NO,G_TP02_PROC
2016/05/25 16:25:22,0,0,0,NO_DEF,-2147483650
TIMEFORMATTED,HDR_SYNC,HDR_SEC,HDR_MSEC,G_CCSDS_VERSION,G_CCSDS_VERSION(RAw
2016/05/25 16:25:22,464374526,1464193527,206,0,0          
TIMEFORMATTED,G_TP01_OPER_ID,G_TP01_OPER_ID(RAW),G_TP02_PROC_NO,G_TP02_PROC
2016/05/25 16:25:26,0,0,0,NO_DEF,-2147483654
TIMEFORMATTED,HDR_SYNC,HDR_SEC,HDR_MSEC,G_CCSDS_VERSION,G_CCSDS_VERSION(RAw
2016/05/25 16:25:26,464374526,1464193532,206,0,0    
TIMEFORMATTED,G_TP01_OPER_ID,G_TP01_OPER_ID(RAW),G_TP02_PROC_NO,G_TP02_PROC
2016/05/25 16:25:27,0,0,0,NO_DEF,-   2147483655
TIMEFORMATTED,HDR_SYNC,HDR_SEC,HDR_MSEC,G_CCSDS_VERSION,G_CCSDS_VERSION(RAW
2016/05/25 16:25:31,464374526,1464193537,207,0,0
```

Second example:

File 1:

```
TIMEFORMATTED,G_TP01_OPER_ID,G_TP01_OPER_ID(RAW),G_TP02_PROC_NO,G_TP02_PROC_NO(R
2014/04/07 16:00:30,0,0,0,NO_DEF,-2147483647
2014/04/07 16:00:35,0,0,0,NO_DEF,-2147483648
2014/04/07 16:00:40,0,0,0,NO_DEF,-2147483649
2014/04/07 16:00:45,0,0,0,NO_DEF,-2147483650
2014/04/07 16:00:50,0,0,0,NO_DEF,-2147483651
2014/04/07 16:00:55,0,0,0,NO_DEF,-2147483652
2014/04/07 16:00:60,0,0,0,NO_DEF,-2147483653
```

File 2:

```
TIMEFORMATTED,CCSDS_VERSION,CCSDS_VERSION(RAW),CCSDS_TYPE,CCSDS_TYPE(RAW),CCSDS_2HDR_FLAG,CCSDS_2HDR_FLAG(RAW),ID
2014/04/07 16:00:43,0,0,0,0,1,1,544
2014/04/07 16:00:45,0,0,0,0,1,3,544
2014/04/07 16:00:47,0,0,0,0,1,1,544
2014/04/07 16:00:49,0,0,0,0,4,1,544
2014/04/07 16:00:51,0,0,0,0,1,1,544
2014/04/07 16:00:53,0,0,0,0,1,7,544
2014/04/07 16:00:55,0,0,0,0,8,1,544
2014/04/07 16:00:57,0,0,0,0,1,2,544
2014/04/07 16:00:59,0,0,0,0,3,1,544
2014/04/07 16:00:61,0,0,0,0,1,1,544
2014/04/07 16:00:63,0,0,0,0,1,9,544
2014/04/07 16:00:65,0,0,0,0,4,1,544
2014/04/07 16:00:67,0,0,0,0,1,1,544
```

Output: I prefer the headers to be attached like first output example, but
I’ll take this if it is easier.

```
2014/04/07 16:00:40,0,0,0,NO_DEF,-2147483649
2014/04/07 16:00:43,0,0,0,0,1,1,544
2014/04/07 16:00:45,0,0,0,NO_DEF,-2147483650
2014/04/07 16:00:45,0,0,0,0,1,3,544
2014/04/07 16:00:45,0,0,0,NO_DEF,-2147483650
2014/04/07 16:00:47,0,0,0,0,1,1,544
2014/04/07 16:00:45,0,0,0,NO_DEF,-2147483650
2014/04/07 16:00:49,0,0,0,0,4,1,544
2014/04/07 16:00:50,0,0,0,NO_DEF,-2147483651
2014/04/07 16:00:51,0,0,0,0,1,1,544
2014/04/07 16:00:50,0,0,0,NO_DEF,-2147483651
2014/04/07 16:00:53,0,0,0,0,1,7,544
2014/04/07 16:00:55,0,0,0,NO_DEF,-2147483652
2014/04/07 16:00:55,0,0,0,0,8,1,544
2014/04/07 16:00:55,0,0,0,NO_DEF,-2147483652
2014/04/07 16:00:57,0,0,0,0,1,2,544
2014/04/07 16:00:55,0,0,0,NO_DEF,-2147483652
2014/04/07 16:00:59,0,0,0,0,3,1,544
2014/04/07 16:00:60,0,0,0,NO_DEF,-2147483653
2014/04/07 16:00:61,0,0,0,0,1,1,544
```

Comment: Why is your output file in pairs of lines? Why not join the records into one line?

Comment: I'd use `sort` to merge the 2 files together, then write a simple perl script that will insert the last seen 6 column record before any 7 column record. Then a second pass to remove redundant 6 column records. Otherwise you have to open both files at the same time.

Comment: Thanks for the response Mark. I'm not sure I understand your question, but they are in pairs because file1 is used for metadata for file2 so I have to match the closest timestamp from both files and append the matching (or closest) file1 row to the top of a file2 row. I then need to split them into their own separate files. These files are only little snippets so the values in the columns may not be real. I can sent two real files, but they are large. Thanks again!

Comment: I had tried the sort/merge and that worked fairly well with sorting them into one file in correct order, however, I don't know how to split the matches into separate files because some file2 rows (up to 5 or so) are assigned with only one file2 row while some are 1 to 1. This would work if I can split them properly (i.e the separate files may have 1 to 1, or 1 to many matches).

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here it is. I prepended a `1,` to file1 and a `2,` to file2, so that I can split them apart again. That is the first 2 lines of the script.

Then merge the two files together on the time stamp (which is now field 2), the 3rd line. The merge operation is very efficient assuming the files are already sorted. I also sort (minor) on the first field, because we want the lines from file1 to come before file2 if the filestamps are identical.

The perl script does:

1. removes the first field (saves it into `$1`)
2. if $1 == "1", saves the most recent line from file1, but doesn't print it.
3. When it sees a type "2", then it prints the most recent type "1" line (`$last`), and the type "2" line.

The a.sh script:

```
pa-dev00$ cat a.sh
perl -pe 's/^/1,/' file1 > file1a
perl -pe 's/^/2,/' file2 > file2a
sort -m -t, -k2,2 -k1,1 file1a file2a | perl -ne 's/^(.),//; if ($1 == "1") {$last=$_; } else { print $last; print $_; }'
```

Here is the output

```
pa-dev00$ ./a.sh
2014/04/07 16:00:40,0,0,0,NO_DEF,-2147483649
2014/04/07 16:00:43,0,0,0,0,1,1,544
2014/04/07 16:00:45,0,0,0,NO_DEF,-2147483650
2014/04/07 16:00:45,0,0,0,0,1,3,544
2014/04/07 16:00:45,0,0,0,NO_DEF,-2147483650
2014/04/07 16:00:47,0,0,0,0,1,1,544
2014/04/07 16:00:45,0,0,0,NO_DEF,-2147483650
2014/04/07 16:00:49,0,0,0,0,4,1,544
2014/04/07 16:00:50,0,0,0,NO_DEF,-2147483651
2014/04/07 16:00:51,0,0,0,0,1,1,544
2014/04/07 16:00:50,0,0,0,NO_DEF,-2147483651
2014/04/07 16:00:53,0,0,0,0,1,7,544
2014/04/07 16:00:55,0,0,0,NO_DEF,-2147483652
2014/04/07 16:00:55,0,0,0,0,8,1,544
2014/04/07 16:00:55,0,0,0,NO_DEF,-2147483652
2014/04/07 16:00:57,0,0,0,0,1,2,544
2014/04/07 16:00:55,0,0,0,NO_DEF,-2147483652
2014/04/07 16:00:59,0,0,0,0,3,1,544
2014/04/07 16:00:60,0,0,0,NO_DEF,-2147483653
2014/04/07 16:00:61,0,0,0,0,1,1,544
2014/04/07 16:00:60,0,0,0,NO_DEF,-2147483653
2014/04/07 16:00:63,0,0,0,0,1,9,544
2014/04/07 16:00:60,0,0,0,NO_DEF,-2147483653
2014/04/07 16:00:65,0,0,0,0,4,1,544
2014/04/07 16:00:60,0,0,0,NO_DEF,-2147483653
2014/04/07 16:00:67,0,0,0,0,1,1,544
```

This should be pretty darn efficient. Each step should be linear, so it will just scale with the size of the files.

Comment: Thanks Mark, I will try this. I used the same sort on my real files and it worked fairly well, but of course it keeps the other file1 rows (metadata rows that are not matched to file2 data) that I don't need . I haven't used perl before on bash so I'll see how that goes.